# Update ASP:Parameter with Value from URL Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I would like to be able to collect a URL Parameter and pass it through to a SelectParameter.

I thought something like this would work but i may be wrong in my approach of translating some code from the Code Behind to the display level

```
<asp:GridView ID="CountryGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid" OnRowEditing="CountryGridView_RowEditing">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="i_SK_Accom" HeaderText="i_SK_Accom" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="Accom_Code" HeaderText="Accom Code" />
                        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="Accom_Name" HeaderText="Accom Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OP49_Required" HeaderText="OP49 Required?" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Weekly" HeaderText="Weekly" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Daily" HeaderText="Daily" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" ControlStyle-CssClass="ImageButton" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Get_Country" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JFAAdmin %>" SelectCommand="IFACE_JFA_ACCOM" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="IFACE_JFA_ACCOM" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="Statement" Type="String" DefaultValue="CountryGridSelect" />
                        <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="i_FK_CountryID" Type="String" DefaultValue="Request["i_FK_CountryID"].Trim().ToString()" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The Request["i_FK_CountryID"].Trim().ToString() is the URL Parameter im trying to capture to pass through as i_FK_CountryID Parameter

Thanks for any help.

Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QueryStringParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx) for this:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter
     Name="i_FK_CountryID"
     Type="String"
     QueryStringField="i_FK_CountryID" />
```